# Moderation using lavaan package in R

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I am writing the model syntax for my model to run in lavaan package using R. I have a factor created (which is my independent variable), 4 dependent variables (I will test 4 different models for each separate DV), and I have four moderating variables that I want to include in each model. All variables except the factor are observed variables.

I am having difficulty with how to include the moderating variable effects in the syntax. Would it look something like this below? Also, how can I have variables like age and sex as covariates in all models? Thank you for your guidance.

Y - DV; F1 - factor; X1 - X4: Moderating variables 1 through 4

Y ~ F1 + F1*X1 + F1*X2 + F1*X3 + F1*X4